# Grounding for a battery

Tags: circuit-design, grounding

Given a 9V battery as the only voltage source for a circuit, where is the Ground usually put? Is there a standard, for example, that puts the negative terminal at 0 and the positive at +9?

Does it every vary, or are there usually hard-set rules for grounding?

Comment: What do you mean when you say grounding? How did you plan on physically "putting" your ground somewhere? I am just trying to understand your context because ground and grounding can mean many things, correct or otherwise. Sometimes it's the voltage node your circuit uses as a reference for its analog or digital signals. In other cases, it's what you are treating as zero volts to measure other nodes with respect to (using something like a battery powered multi-meter which floats on the circuit). In other cases, it means connecting a node in a circuit to something else to anchor its potential.

Comment: ground is wherever you want to share wires , low impedance high current or no current with RF noise.

Ground can be floating or earth grounded and by definition =0V reference. It  can be any DC voltage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a standard?
>   Not a universal one writing... but by popularity positive grounds and coaxial center negative have faded fast in the  last 2 decades, due to user error.

Since ground only means a 0V reference, it does not matter locally, only when interacing. Zero Volts,   0V is always  floating , unless connected to anything that is connected grid earth or PE, Protective Earth Gnd, which, coincidentally is also floating ;) in the  Universe, but locally , it is our biggest  common-mode 0V reference. Yet with trans-atlantic cables there can be a thousand volts difference. E.g. VGA monitors are PE grounded.

Like all voltage sources, even 0V has impedance so ground shift voltage depends in V(f)=I(f)*Z(f).   It has both differential mode impedance (Zdm) and common mode (Zcm). So floating means at DC high R but at some frequency that Z can  drop low by conductor length/gap ratio due to inherent capacitance.

Grid tower grounds need to be < 100 Ohms for lightning protection. But grid to home much less, so it is distributed.

Answer (score 1):

You can put ground wherever you want; the grounded points in your circuit will then all be at 0V (by definition/convention), and, theoretically, they will all look as the same node (ie, no impedance whatsoever between them).
Look at it this way: Batteries, and other voltage sources, only set a voltage difference between their terminals, which means that ungrounded circuits have an indeterminate voltage at every point, with only voltage differences being defined. So hooking some point to ground is simply a matter of fixing an origin for the scale.

Answer (score 1):

"Ground" in most circuits is just the point we want to call "Zero Volts" and use as a reference when measuring voltages elsewhere in the circuit.

In most circuits these days, "Ground/Reference" is the negative terminal of the power supply, but in some cases it might be the positive terminal.  (Old 6 Volt cars were often "positive Ground", but negative ground is common now.)

In many analog circuits, "Ground/Reference" is the center point of the power supply, so you can have both positive and negative voltages in the circuit.